# what is [] in pine-script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

**what is value of _smoothed[1] variable in below code?**

```
f_zrsi( _source, _length ) => rsi( _source, _length ) - 50

f_rsi( _source, _length, _mode ) =>
    //  get base rsi
    float _zrsi = f_zrsi( _source, _length )

    //  smoothing in a manner similar to HA open, but rather using the realtime
    //  rsi in place of the prior close value.
    var float _smoothed = na
    _smoothed := na( _smoothed[1] ) ? _zrsi : ( _smoothed[1] + _zrsi ) / 2

    //  return the requested mode
    _mode ? _smoothed : _zrsi
```

Comment: history-referencing operator https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#history-referencing-operator

Answer (score 0):

It is called the [History Reference Operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) and is used to access historical data.

In your example, `_smoothed[1]` returns the previous value of `_smoothed`.

Comment: what is previous value of the variable in that code? the current and first value is **na**,  `var float _smoothed = na`.    there is no previous value.

Comment: You need to understand how [series](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Type_system.html#series) data type and pine's [execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html) works.